# Recursive iteration of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion, tail-recursion

I have an array of classes:

```
const transferClasses = [
  {
    id: "c5d91430-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
    name: "Class1",
    isTransfer: false,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    id: "775cb75d-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
    name: "Class2",
    isTransfer: false,
    children: [
      {
        id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
        name: "Class2-1",
        isTransfer: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4cc",
        name: "Class2-2",
        isTransfer: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4de",
            name: "Class2-2-1",
            isTransfer: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f1ce",
            name: "Class2-2-2",
            isTransfer: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to iterate over an array and turn it into a flat list. For expample:

```
const flatList = [
  {
    id: "c5d91430-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
    name: "Class1",
    isTransfer: false,
    childrenId: null,
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "775cb75d-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
    name: "Class2",
    isTransfer: false,
    childrenId: [
      "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
      "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4cc",
    ],
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
    name: "Class2-1",
    isTransfer: false,
    childrenId: [],
    parentId: ["775cb75d-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc"],
  },
  {
    id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc",
    name: "Class2-2",
    isTransfer: false,
    childrenId: [
      "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4de",
      "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f1ce",
    ],
    parentId: ["775cb75d-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc"],
  },
  {
    id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4de",
    name: "Class2-2-1",
    isTransfer: false,
    childrenId: [],
    parentId: ["89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc"],
  },
  {
    id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f1ce",
    name: "Class2-2-2",
    isTransfer: false,
    childrenId: [],
    parentId: ["89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc"],
  },
];
```

Each element needs to be given a list of id's of its parents and children.

Here is my function code. It seems I figured out what to do with the children, but there are no ideas at all how to add parents.

```
export const getFlatList = (classes) => {
  return classes.map((cl) => {
    
    const getChildIds = (classes) => {
      return classes.map((cl) => {
        if (cl.children.length > 0) {
          getChildIds(cl.children);
        } else {
          return cl.id;
        }
        return cl.id;
      });
    };

    return {
      id: cl.id,
      name: cl.name,
      isTransfer: cl.isTransfer,
      children: getChildIds(cl.children),
      parentId: ?? // :(
    };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like that. We start from the top and then look for children. If found, we go one level deeper until the children array is empty.

```js
const flattenArray = (array) => {
    let flatArray = [];

    const traverse = (node, parentId = null) => {
        const { children, ...restOfNode } = node;

        flatArray.push({
            ...restOfNode,
            childrenId: children ? children.map(child => child.id) : [],
            parentId: [parentId],
        });

        if (node.children.length) {
            node.children.forEach((child) => traverse(child, node.id));
        }
    }

    array.forEach((arrayItem) => traverse(arrayItem));

    return flatArray;
}
```

jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/34cL8jh1/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function `getFlatList()` to flatten the input, using a recursive approach, iterating through the input and pushing each object found to the result array.

We'd append the parentId and childrenId to each newly created object in the output

```js
function getFlatList ( input, parentId = null) {
    let result = [];
    for(let k in input) {
        if (input[k] && typeof(input[k]) === 'object') {
          if (input[k].name) {
              const { children, ...obj } = input[k]
              result.push({
                  ...obj,
                  childrenId: children.map(c => c.id),
                  parentId
              })
          }
          result.push(...getFlatList(input[k], input.id))
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const transferClasses = [ { id: "c5d91430-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc", name: "Class1", isTransfer: false, children: [], }, { id: "775cb75d-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc", name: "Class2", isTransfer: false, children: [ { id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc", name: "Class2-1", isTransfer: false, children: [], }, { id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4cc", name: "Class2-2", isTransfer: false, children: [ { id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4de", name: "Class2-2-1", isTransfer: false, children: [], }, { id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f1ce", name: "Class2-2-2", isTransfer: false, children: [], }, ], }, ], }, ];

console.log('Flattened: ');
console.log(getFlatList (transferClasses))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about it:

```js
const flatten = (classes, parentId = null) => 
  classes.flatMap(({children = [], id, ...rest}) => [
    {id, ...rest, parentId, childrenId: children.map(({id}) => id)}, 
    ...flatten(children, id)
  ])

const transferClasses = [{id: "c5d91430-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc", name: "Class1", isTransfer: false, children: []}, {id: "775cb75d-aaab-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc", name: "Class2", isTransfer: false, children: [{id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f5cc", name: "Class2-1", isTransfer: false, children: []}, {id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4cc", name: "Class2-2", isTransfer: false, children: [{id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f4de", name: "Class2-2-1", isTransfer: false, children: []}, {id: "89134f56-3ef6-ed11-8daf-85953743f1ce", name: "Class2-2-2", isTransfer: false, children: []}]}]}]

console.log(flatten(transferClasses))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We flatten our list with `flatMap`, each step returning an array consisting of our current item (without its `children` property), and the result of recurring on our list of children.  We pass `parentId` through the recursion, defaulting to `null` if it's not supplied, and we find `childrenId` by plucking the `id` values off our children.  And that's it.  The beauty of recursion handles everything else for us.